# Inserting a DIV Block Into a Listing of Excerpts?

Tags: css, excerpt

I'm sure there has to be a tutorial for this, I just can't find it.  I'm also pretty confident there's numerous ways to do this and I'm looking for the best.    I've never had to do this before, so I've never asked...

I want to insert a DIV into a list of excerpts.  For example, take a look at: http://www.premiumpixels.com/wordpress-themes/ where Orman added a div asking users to subscribe into his excerpts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a counter to your loop or use a conditional statement with `$wp_query->current_post`, just before the 'endwhile', and add the div when the counter/post number  reaches a certain value. please paste the full code of your template into a http://pastebin.com/ and post the link to it here, if you need more details.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/R3VMfGPR
Thanks for the help!

Comment: example code: http://pastebin.com/9Gm0hQ8e

Comment: Thanks I'm getting the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' 
I'm bad at PHP and I don't know what's causing it.

Comment: i missed a closing php tag - corrected http://pastebin.com/BvNgCGjT

Comment: Michael, thanks for taking the time to help me out!  I really appreciate it.